# Custom Exception Class not printing error, but rather the input

Tags: python, exception

I have a custom exception I want to use that is analogous to the following. When I handle the exception, I want my message to print the error - i.e., "ShortPasswordError: Luke" - rather than just the password - "Luke".  Here's what I'm talking about exactly.

```
class AuthenticationError(ValueError):
    pass

class ShortPasswordError(AuthenticationError):
    pass 

def createPassword(password):
    if len(password) < 10: 
        raise ShortPasswordError(password)

password = input("Enter a password: ")


try: 
    createPassword(password)
except AuthenticationError as e: 
    print(f"Looks like there's an error with your password. Does {e} ring any bells?")
```

Here's what's currently happening though

```
Enter a password: Luke
Looks like there's an error with your password. Does Luke ring any bells?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `repr`, not `str`, to format the exception in the f-string.

```
print(f"Looks like there's an error with your password. Does {e!r} ring any bells?")
```

This will produce

```
$ python3 tmp.py
Enter a password: Luke
Looks like there's an error with your password. Does ShortPasswordError('Luke') ring any bells?
```

Comment: Thanks!  Didn't know that was necessary.  Appreciate it brother!